# How to read the downloaded file (xml, txt) from a Multipart file and save this data line by line to the database

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jdbc

I'm just learning Java(spring boot), but I need to make a small project like this. I need to upload a file (xml, txt) to the server, read it line by line and put it in the database (in the table there is a field - body (type string) to put the contents of the downloaded file there.

I implemented the file upload to the server (line reading too), but I cannot put this data in the database. The downloaded file has a variable "complete Data" which contains the data of the downloaded file. How to pass it to the variable "body", so that it is stored in the database? Or how to do it differently?

I found examples of how to put in the database the file itself, but I need to put the contents of the file (the internal text).

```
/*File download*/

@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("name")String name,
                                                 @RequestParam("file")MultipartFile file){
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();

                String completeData = new String(bytes);

                BufferedOutputStream stream =
                        new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(name + "-uploaded")));
                stream.write(bytes);
                stream.close();
                return completeData;
//              return "Вы удачно загрузили " + name + " B " + name + "-uploaded !";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "Вам не удалось загрузить " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
            }
        }else{
            return "Вам не удалось загрузить " + name + " потому что файл пустой.";
        }
    }

/*Domain*/
public class Docs {
    private String body;

    public Docs(){
        super();
    }
        public Docs(String body){
        super();
        this.body=body;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I passed my variable "complete Data" to dao.addFile

```
dao.add(completeData);
```

Dao.class:

```
public void add_b_utmdocs(string body){
        template.update ("insert into docs (body) values (?)", body);
    }
```